# Octopus: unable to download packages from local feed

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, octopus-deploy, ccnet-config

I'm having some troubles with a situation and I would like to get your help. I'm using `CruiseControl.NET` to create the packages of my builds and it creates them correctly. The package versions are beeing stored at a folder in a remote machine.

However, when I use `Octopus`, I set a local feed with the correct URI for that folder. The folder has the right permissions (read/write). But when I try to create a release of the package in Octopus, it can't reach the version of the package. Plus, when I test it to get the list of packages, the list is always empty. So, I don't get the version when I try to create the release.

[image: version list empty]

I already tried to change the credentials for the access (using another user), and I already changed the directory. I can ping the remote machine, I can enter via remote connection with those users, and I can reach the folder in Explorer. Plus, I double checked the folder permissions... But I'm still getting the same problem. I don't know what is going on and Octopus doesn't allow me to deploy the package without a version.

I'm running `Octopus 1.5.1.1652` and `CruiseControl.NET 1.8.3.0`.